# Generalized Hough R-Table

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I am trying to implement the generalized Hough transform as presented in [this paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~dana/HoughT.pdf) in MATLAB. I've also tried using [this document](https://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/GeneralizedHough.pdf) to understand the algorithm. I am stuck on figuring out how to calculate the gradient angle to find Φ to use in the R-Table.

I have tried to run this [matlab implementation](http://www.irit.fr/~Julien.Pinquier/Docs/Hough_transform.html), but the contour function tries to access negative indices. The missing functions are below.

distance.m

```
function [ d ] = distance( x1, y1, x2, y2 )
  d = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 );   
end
```

barycenter.m

```
function [ xo, yo ] = barycenter( img )
%   gravitational center coordinates of a shape 

  [rows, cols] = size(img);
  x = ones(rows, 1)*(1:cols);
  y = (1:rows)'*ones(1,cols);
  area = sum(sum(img));
  xo = sum(sum(double(img) .* x)) / area;
  yo = sum(sum(double(img) .* y)) / area;

end
```

modelHough.m

```
function [H]=ModelHough(imgRGB)
% Generalized Hough Transform Modeling

% Image Binarization
imgBW = rgb2gray(imgRGB);
imgBI = imgBW < 255;

% Retrieving information about the contour: points and number (N)
N = contour(imgBI);

% Model initialization:
    % row = beta value * 100
    % column = number of the couple (alpha, distance)
    % 3rd dimension: 1 = alpha, 2 = distance
H=zeros(round(100*2*pi),N,2);

% Compute of the barycenter coordinates
[ xo, yo ] = barycenter(imgBI);

% for each contour point
for i=1:N

    % beta compute for ith contour point
    b = beta(N, imgBI, i);

    % research of the first column
    k=1;
    while H(b+1,k,2)~=0
       k=k+1;
    end

    % compute of the alpha value
    H(b+1, k, 1) = alpha(N, i, imgBI);

    % compute of the distance value
    H(b+1, k, 2) = distance( xo, yo, i, b );

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a suitable edge detector. You could start off with the [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). The gradient angle is atan(Gy/Gx) as described in the wiki article.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a common edge detector for detecting edges you should change `countor.m` on row 14 to something like below:

```
while (img(i,j)~=1)
```