# How to decompose a shape into a set of basic shapes?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, geometry

I have a hand drawn shape ***I*** as input. The format of ***I*** is a sequence of (x,y) coordinates. It could be characters in a language or other shapes. Given a set of basic shapes ***S*** (eg { vertical line, horizontal line, circle, semi-circle} ). I would like to decompose ***I*** in terms of ***S***.

Is this a standard operation with a standard name?

Is there a standard algorithm/classifier to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplementary to @Don Reba 's answer, I would attach the [original publication](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~dana/HoughT.pdf) on generalized Hough transform for your reference. Herein you can see the angle of line can be controlled with `theta` parameter in the curve equation. And the half of circle is controlled with the coordinates `xr` and `yr` in the curve equation. There is a pseudocode on ellipse detection in the paper for your reference. And generalized hough transform can be even used to detect arbitrary shapes with the use of directional information. In SO there was a easy Matlab code [on the algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176157/generalized-hough-r-table).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the generalized Hough transform to match letter contours against basic shapes. You would need a different transform for every kind of shape.